# Is it a good idea to use word2vec for encoding of categorical features?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, categorical-data, feature-engineering

I am facing a binary prediction task and have a set of features of which all are categorical. A key challenge is therefore to encode those categorical features to numbers and I was looking for smart ways to do so. 
I stumbled over word2vec, which is mostly used for NLP, but I was wondering whether I could use it to encode my variables, i.e. simply take the weights of the neural net as the encoded features.

However, I am not sure, whether it is a good idea since, the context words, which serve as the input features in word2vec are in my case more or less random, in contrast to real sentences which word2vec was originially made for.

Do you guys have any advice, thoughts, recommendations on this?

Answer (score 4):

You should look into **entity embedding** if you are searching for a way to utilize embeddings for categorical variables.

- google has a good crash course on the topic: https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/embeddings/categorical-input-data
- this is a good paper on arxiv written by a team from a Kaggle competition: https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.06737

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible to use the word2vec algorithm to train up 'dense embeddings' for things like keywords, tags, categories, and so forth. It's been done, sometimes beneficially.

Whether it's a good idea in your case will depend on your data & goals – the only way to know for sure is to try it, and evaluate the results versus your alternatives. (For example, if the number of categories is modest from a controlled vocabulary, one-hot encoding of the categories may be practical, and depending on the kind of binary classifier you use downstream, the classifier may itself be able to learn the same sorts of subtle interrelationships between categories that could also otherwise be learned via a word2vec model. On the other hand, if categories are very numerous & chaotic, the pre-step of 'compressing' them into a smaller-dimensional space, where similar categories have similar representational vectors, may be more helpful.)

That such tokens don't quite have the same frequency distributions & surrounding contexts as true natural language text may mean it's worth trying a wider range of non-default training options on any word2vec model.

In particular, if your categories don't have a natural ordering giving rise to meaningful near-neighbors relationships, using a giant `window` (so all words in a single 'text' are in each others' contexts) may be worth considering.

Recent versions of the Python `gensim` `Word2Vec` allow changing a parameter named `ns_exponent` – which was fixed at `0.75` in many early implementations, but at least one paper has suggested can usefully vary far from that value for certain corpus data and recommendation-like applications.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Do you by chance recall a paper which uses word2vec as encoding strategy?